# How to pass named parameter list to an opening windows form application

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

I have a windows form application
Lets call it B
Now i have another application. Lets call it A

A will start B as a new process
Now i want to pass named parameter list to B and use them in B
How can i do that ?

What i mean is example parameter list

```
{job:"computer engineer",age:"32",experience:"3 years"}
```

Also these parameter list should be optional. Sometimes i may pass 5 parameters sometimes 0

And how will i read these parameters at start up on B application

So what is the way of doing this ? thank you

c#

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're calling your "B" process with Process.Start, the following should work:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string fileName, string arguments)
```

And your "B" processes main thread should accept an array to house possible arguments that you can then iterate over.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //your code to decipher arguments here
}
```

Comment: yes i will use process start. but how can i read them as named parameters ?

Comment: I'm not sure of best practices here but perhaps this suggestion can spark a better response or get you started on the right path.  If you pass your arguments as strings (e.g. "job: CE" "age: 32" "exp: 3 years") you could then run a switch statement that evaluates the first three characters of your string to point it into the proper direction.  Obviously this is not the most elegant solution (it forces you to hard code 3 letter codes in the same string as your actual parameters) but it has the potential to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Your switch statement would need to go inside of a loop that iterates over your array to parse each parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of doing this.

First is to use command line arguments. If you were to call you process (from the command line) as:

```
your.exe -job "computer engineer" -age 32 -experience "3 years"
```

You would then duplicate this in your code by settings the `arguments` in your process's start options. You would then have to set up your process to look for all of these flags, remembering that they can all be optional, and so on.

The second option (and this is a bit more flexible) is to make a file that holds the values you are passing over, and read it from your launched process. You could make this XML, or straight values.

**Edit**: here is an example of the first option

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "your exe path";
startInfo.Arguments = "your argument list";
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
```

I don't want to tell you how to format your argument string; that should be up to you to decide. However, I will recommend [a library](http://cmdline.codeplex.com/) to use that might make the parsing on the receiving end a bit easier.

Comment: i will use this one to start : System.Diagnostics.Process.Start. can you make example in your post thank you

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG See my edit, and see the library link for some help with parsing the arguments.